# console.logging the result (value) returns correct value but updating(setState) a state returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

In a useEffect, the task is to do a addition and subtraction base on a condition. The result comes out to be correct when console logged in the useEffect block but when I update(setState) a state with the result and try to console log the state outside the useEffect block I get a different(wrong) answer from

I have tried using callback during the setState or updating the state

```
const [Total, setTotal] = useState(1000);
const [keeper, setKeeper] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {

if (shippingCharges !== 0){
  let fee = 0;
  let total = 0;
const CheckFees = (newFee) => {
    if (fee !== 0) {
      let result = (Total -= keeper);
      total = result;
    }

    fee = newFee;
    setKeeper(newFee);
    let result = (Total += fee);
    // console.log(result);
    total = result;
    console.log("New fee: " + fee);
    console.log("New total: " + total);
  };
}
 CheckFees(shippingCharges);
 console.log(total);
  setTotal(total, () => {
    console.log(total, "updating");
  })}, 
[shippingCharges, showShipping])
```

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: It has been updated now ( with code)

Comment: @ImoEmpire it says shippingCharges is undefined. Can you post the entire js file content?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use setTotal with a callback as second params.

If you want to see the updated result when total value is changed you can do as follow by using another useEffect that trigger total value :

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("Updated total value: ", Total);
 }, [Total])
```

Also, the total value that you are trying to console.log in the callback can be in conflict with the total variable previously created. Be carefull when you're naming you variable/states